Issue with Telegram Dates
Flight 1234 was originally scheduled in the daily flight plan for 02.12.24 (Planned date) but was rescheduled to 04.12.24 due to weather conditions.
In the specialized flight operations software:

The Planned date remains as 02.12.24.
The Estimated and Actual dates are updated to 04.12.24.

On 04.12.24, LDM and other telegrams referencing 04.12.24 are received. However, the software displays the following event:
"Flight 1234 for 04.12.24 was not found in the daily flight plan."
As a result, the telegrams are not linked to the flight.
Could this issue be caused by:

An error in the software's algorithm, which seems to link telegrams to the Planned (scheduled) date instead of the Actual date?
A formatting issue in the telegrams, as IATA (or other) regulations specify using the Planned (scheduled) date?

If the latter, could you please clarify which specific documents state that telegrams must always use the Planned (scheduled) date rather than the Actual date?
Thank you for your assistance!

This information should be available in the IATA Airport Handling Manual (AHM 583 message). Do you have access to this manual?

@mins hi and ty for reply! Unfortunately, I do not have access to the IATA AHM. Too expensive for me ):
